# What's the load order of javascript files in the firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

There are some codes like this:

in the `main.js` :

```
 var pagemod = PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('content.js')]
 }

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 322,
  height: 427,
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  include:["*"]  
});
```

in the `panel.html`, `panel.js` is loaded by `<script src="js/panel.js"></script>` .
I want to make the js file load order to be like "`main.js->content.js->panel.js`",sometimes it works, but sometimes the result is "`main.js->panel.js->content.js`".
 
So,How does the firefox addon load the js files?

Comment: Why would you want the code loaded in order?

Comment: Smells like a code smell to me :)

Comment: @Jocke because some js files must set up listener first for the following messages.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, I don't know what does it mean.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell